# MVC 3 htmlhelper extension method to wrap around content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, htmlextensions

I searched but could not find any quick solutions for an MVC 3 htmlhelper to create a wrapper method. What I'm looking for is something like:

```
@html.createLink("caption", "url")
{
    <html> content in tags </html>
}
```

the result should have

```
<a href="url" title="Caption">
  <html> content in tags </html>
</a>
```

Any help with this.

Comment: Are you asking if its possible to do something like this: `@Html.ActionLink("<span class='red'>Hello</span> World", "MyAction")` ?

Comment: No not that. I know there is BeginForm() and EndForm() kind of approach to handle this kind of scenario but when doing this on a large scale can cause an issue if u forget one end tag.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean? You wouldn't use `BeginForm` in this scenario? You'd use `BeginForm` to create a form, not an anchor link.

Comment: Beginform is just for the purpose of illustration.. not for actual use.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail exactly what you want, with a real example of how you wish it to be used?

Comment: I've added an answer that I think is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The way that this is done with BeginForm is that the return type `MvcForm` impliments `IDisposable` so that when used within a `using` statement, the `Dispose` method of `MvcForm` writes out the closing `</form>` tag.

You can write an extension method that does exactly the same thing.

Here's one I just wrote to demonstrate.

**First off, the extension method:**

```
public static class ExtensionTest
{
    public static MvcAnchor BeginLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer
                        .Write(tagBuilder.ToString(
                                             TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        return new MvcAnchor(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
    }
}
```

And here's our new type, MvcAnchor:

```
public class MvcAnchor : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TextWriter _writer;
    public MvcAnchor(ViewContext viewContext)
    {
        _writer = viewContext.Writer;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this._writer.Write("</a>");
    }
}
```

In your views you can now do:

```
@{
    using (Html.BeginLink())
    { 
        @Html.Raw("Hello World")
    }
}
```

Which yields the result:

```html
<a>Hello World</a>
```

Expanding this slightly to deal with your exact requirement:

```
public static MvcAnchor BeginLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
                                   string href, 
                                   string title)
{
    var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
    tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("href",href);
    tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("title", title);
    htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(tagBuilder
                                    .ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
    return new MvcAnchor(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
}
```

and our view:

```
@{
  using (Html.BeginLink("http://stackoverflow.com", "The Worlds Best Q&A site"))
  { 
      @Html.Raw("StackOverflow - Because we really do care")
  }
}
```

which yields the result:

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" title="The Worlds Best Q&amp;A site">
   StackOverflow - Because we really do care</a>
```

Comment: this is beautiful. you just saved me half a day :))

Comment: Note to others. In your markup, note that @Jamie Dixon uses the Class HTML not ExtensionTest.

Answer (score 9):

There's also another way, without disposable trick. It's less work, great for small helpers. I answered similar question, and don't want to copy everything, but here's a short example:

```
@helper Paragraph(string cssClass, Func<object, object> markup) {
    <p class="@cssClass">@markup.DynamicInvoke(this.ViewContext)</p>
}
```

Usage of this helper looks like this:

```
@Paragraph("highlited", 
    @<text>
        Look, a @Html.ActionLink("link", "index")
    </text>
)
```

My full answer to the other similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13801915/808271).

Answer (score 2):

At its simplest level something like this would do it

```
public static MvcHtmlString SomeLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string href, string     title,  string content )
    {
        var urlHelper = ((Controller)htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller).Url;
        //var url = urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues);

        var someLink = new TagBuilder("a");
        someLink.MergeAttribute("href", href);
        someLink.InnerHtml = content;

        return new MvcHtmlString(someLink.ToString());
    }
```