# HtmlHelper extension to wrap around content for ServiceStack Markdown Razor

Tags: c#, .net, razor, servicestack, razor-2

Using [ServiceStack Markdown Razor](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Markdown-Razor), how can I create an HtmlHelper extension method that works like:

> In your views you can now do:

```
@{
    using (Html.BeginLink())
    { 
        @Html.Raw("Hello World")
    }
}
```

> Which yields the result:

```
<a>Hello World</a>
```

from [This StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635063/mvc-3-htmlhelper-extension-method-to-wrap-around-content/10637767#10637767)

ServiceStack Markdown Razor has no concept of `ViewContext`, so I'm unsure how I'd get a Writer the same way as in the SO Answer.

---

**UPDATE**

I can get at the ViewPage's `StringBuilder` directly from:

```
@{ this.ViewPage.Builder }
```

But is this the intended way to access it?  If it was intended to directly access the StringBuilder, wouldn't the `StringBuilder` be exposed from the `HtmlHelper` in lieu of ViewData (from MVC)?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
public static class MyHelpers
{

    public static IHtmlString PrintHelloWorld(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        return helper.Raw("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Just make sure that the class above is in the same namespace as the HtmlHelper.